# Running Android NDK Executable with "su -c" Swallows printf()

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, root

**TLDR; Problem:**

When I run my native Android executable alone with `Runtime.exec()`, I can get its `printf()` outputs from my app. But when I do it with `Runtime.exec("su -c <native executable>")`, I can't get its outputs anymore.

---

**Better explanation:**

So, say I have an Android app that has a native executable called **"executable"**. I rename **"executable"** to **"libexecutable.so"** to trick the apk installer into copying the file over into the device.

Then, the app runs the executable with

```
String executable = context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/lib/libexecutable.so";
String me = context.getPackageName();

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("%s %s", executable, me));
```

From my native executable, whenever I use **`printf()`**, I can get the output in my app with **`p.getInputStream()`**. Perfect.

However, this native executable needs root permissions, so, I run it like this:

```
String su = "su -c";
String executable = context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/lib/libexecutable.so";
String me = context.getPackageName();

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("%s %s %s", su, executable, me));
```

*Now*, whenever my native executable uses `printf()`, I **no longer** can get the output with `p.getInputStream()`.

I looked it up and got to this:
[Java: can't get stdout data from Process unless its manually flushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230837/java-cant-get-stdout-data-from-process-unless-its-manually-flushed)

And tried `fflush(stdout)` in my native executable directly after every `printf()` call, like the page suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: did you try to read stderr?

Comment: I didn't. I just tried it upon your suggestion and looks like you were spot on.. I got "Permission denied". Which is **very** strange to me. My phone **is** rooted *(I've used other root apps fine)*, the Superuser app logs show that it has **Allowed** every single request by my app..

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{
    "su",
    "-c",
    getFilesDir().getParent() + "/lib/libexecutable.so " + getPackageName()
};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
//No more permission denied error
```

Oh, never mind. I got it running with this. Could someone tell me **why** this works and not my initial attempt?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference -- `exec(String)` just tokenizes the string and passes it to `exec(String[])`.  Did you do a `chmod` in there somewhere to set the file's executable bit?

Comment: I didn't. I literally just replaced my string concats with this string array. I didn't even know what chmod was until recently. I'm still very new to this whole Unix thing.

Comment: The real proof of meaningful difference or not would be if your can *break* it again by *reverting* to the original.  If so, this is (puzzlingly) the fix.  If not, it is coincidence and the meaningful change was elsewhere.  Also, it's not clear if you have some mechanism other than the expected output messages to know if the command executed; if not it's possible some subtle mistaken in the other invocation mechanism was simply preventing it from running, rather than from providing collectable output.

Comment: I just tried it as you suggested. String fails with "Permission denied" being output on error stream. String array succeeds.